# How to display array of object within and object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

If you run this code:

```js
myObj = {
  "country": "USA",
  "president": [{
      "number": 1,
      "vice_president": "John Adams"
    },
    {
      "number": 2,
      "vice_president": "John Adams"
    }
  ]
};
var div1 = document.createElement('div');
div1.setAttribute('id', 'test');
document.body.appendChild(div1);
for (x in myObj) {
  document.getElementById("test").innerHTML += myObj[x] + " ";
}
```

You will see the result being something like: USA [object Object],[object Object]

How do i show the value of the president array within myOBJ?

The outcome should be something like:

country: USA

President: number 1 vice_president John Adams

Comment: [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)?

Comment: What output do you expect? Please see [ask] if you haven't already.

Comment: i guess the expected outcome would be something like:
country: USA
President: number 1 vice_president John Adams

Answer (score 0):

Please use `JSON.stringify()` for this. Also to make the printing process look decent, please use `pre` tag instead of `div` tag, so that the formatting is preserved!

```js
myObj = {
  "country": "USA",
  "president": [{
      "number": 1,
      "vice_president": "John Adams"
    },
    {
      "number": 2,
      "vice_president": "John Adams"
    }
  ]
};
var div1 = document.createElement('pre');
div1.setAttribute('id', 'test');
document.body.appendChild(div1);
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML += JSON.stringify(myObj, null, 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below code.

```
myObj = {
  "country": "USA",
  "president": [{
      "number": 1,
      "vice_president": "John Adams"
  },
  {
      "number": 2,
      "vice_president": "John Adams"
  }]
};
let output;
output = 'Country: ' + myObj.country + '<br/>';
for (let president of myObj.president) {
     output += 'President (no ' + president.number + '): ' + president.vice_president + '<br/>';
}
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = output;
```

Output:

```
Country: USA
President (no 1): John Adams
President (no 2): John Adams
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what do you want. Please note that I put to you multiple implementations so you can choose what you want:

```
   var myObj = {
      "country": "USA",
      "president": [{
         "number": 1,
          "vice_president": "John Adams"
      },
      {
         "number": 2,
         "vice_president": "John Adams"
      }
     ]
    };

    // If you want to loop over all your Obj first lever
    for(var k in myObj){
        console.log(k); // Your keys // country, president 
        // If you want loop over president array
        if (myObj[k] instanceof Array){
            var array_obj = myObj[k];
            array_obj.forEach(function(sub_item){
                for(var j in sub_item){
                    console.log('Key ', j);
                    console.log('Value ', sub_item[j]);
                }
            });
        }else{

        }
    }

    // If you want direct access to your array president
    var president = myObj['president'];

    president.forEach(function (item){
        console.log('Presedent Number: ' , item.number);
        console.log('Presedent Name: ', item.vice_president);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
myObj = {
  "country": "USA",
  "president": [{
      "number": 1,
      "vice_president": "John Adams"
    },
    {
      "number": 2,
      "vice_president": "John Adams"
    }
  ]
};

var div1 = document.createElement('div');
div1.setAttribute('id', 'test');
document.body.appendChild(div1);

var exp = '';

for (x in myObj) {
  if(Array.isArray(myObj[x])){
        exp += x + ": ";
        myObj[x].forEach(function(obj , index){
            for(var o in obj){                      
                exp += o +" " + obj[o] + " ";
            }
        })
  }else{
       exp += x + ": " + myObj[x] + " \n"
  }
}
```